# authenticators.xml is missing in wso2 elb

Tags: wso2

I am installing the WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer 2.1.1 in a testing environment. At the end of the startup, it complains about a missing 'authenticators.xml'.

According to the README in /repository/conf, this xml-file should be present in /repository/conf/security.

I copied an existing authenticators.xml from a running EMM, but obviously it doesn't work out-of-the-box, and I don't know which settings I should change.

Does anybody have an appropriate authenticators.xml for an ELB?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a platform.

Comment: This is unusual. WSO2 ELB does not need the authenticators.xml. Whats the exception you get and when do you get it?

Comment: I just wanted to edit the original post, but you beat me to it: apparently this only happens when i try to access the management console through a web browser, when logging in with admin/admin. This is the last error message: [2014-08-02 18:50:06,810] ERROR - DefaultCarbonAuthenticator Configuration context is null.

Comment: The error messages which precede this last error message are: [2014-08-02 18:54:12,618] ERROR - AuthenticatorsConfiguration authenticators.xml file is not available. Carbon Server is starting with thedefault authenticators
[2014-08-02 18:54:12,684] ERROR - AuthenticationAdminClient Error occurred while logging in. With a lot of java messages inbetween.

Is it perhaps ok to continue testing, without accessing the management console through a web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing this answer after reading the two comments:

WSO2 ELB does not need the Carbon console (management console) to work with. Actually, non of its functionality is exposed via the UI. Everything is dealt via the config files. Main config file is the loadbalancer.conf.

Exception you get is reasonable. When a user logs into the carbon console, it goes through a chain of authenticators. In this case, we seem not to ship the authenticators.xml with the ELB pack. Hence the exception. There were plans to remove the carbon console totally from the ELB and there were thoughts otherwise. Some said we need to expose the configs via the UI. But, didn't happen yet.

In summary, you don't need the carbon console to work with the WSO2 ELB. Hence, this exception is harmless.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I suggest that the instructions on the site be changed accordingly, then: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB211/Running+the+Product (the section about "Running the management console"). That's what tripped me :)

Comment: Thanks for the feeedback. We have removed it now.